C# Getting month number from short month
I'm trying to read in the month number from a short month (like this) DateTime.ToString("MMM")
So read in "feb" or "MAR" and return 2 or 3
This is the function I came up with however I am wondering if I can do something with a parseexact and pass in dummy year / day to get the month number from that?
private int GetNumberFromShortMonth(string month)
{
    var monthNo = -1;
    var dt = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        dt = dt.AddMonths(1);

        if (string.Equals(dt.ToString("MMM"), month, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            monthNo = dt.Month;
            break;
        }
    }

    return monthNo;
}


Yes, you are correct. You can do exactly what you asked.

I'd suggest using DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames instead. (Find the index within that, case-insensitively.)

Switch case or dictionary? If this should work only with one culture

@JonSkeet - DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames returns 13 items. The months plus an empty string. Why is that?

var result = Array.IndexOf(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames, month) + 1;

@Enigmativity: I suspect it's for consistency, so it can always return 13 month names (for calendars with 13 months, like the Hebrew calendar in a leap year).

I'd also recommend you consider that other cultures don't use the same strings for month names, so be careful.

What about this:
private static int GetNumberFromShortMonth(string month)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(month, "MMM", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))
    {
        return dt.Month;
    }
        
    return -1;
}


You can use this,
private static int GetNumberFromShortMonth(string month)
{
     month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(month.ToLower());

    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return date.Month;
}


One way to do it is to use DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames which return the following array of values.
["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", ""]

using System.Globalization;

namespace MyProgram;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int NotFound = -1;
        Console.WriteLine($"Jan: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("JAN")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Feb: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("Feb")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Mar: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("mar")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Apr: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("APR")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"May: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("May")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Jun: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("juN")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Jul: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("JUL")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Aug: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("aug")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Sep: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("SEP")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Oct: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("oCt")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Nov: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("NOV")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Dec: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("dec")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Empty string returns NotFound: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("") == NotFound}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Too short returns NotFound: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("De") == NotFound}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Too long returns NotFound: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("Dece") == NotFound}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Only whitespace returns NotFound: {GetNumberFromShortMonth("   ") == NotFound}");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the number of the month from the short month name or -1 if not found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="month"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static int GetNumberFromShortMonth(string month)
    {
        const int NotFound = -1;
        if (month.Length != 3 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(month))
        {
            return NotFound;
        }
        var index = Array.IndexOf(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames, NormalizeCasing(month));
        return index == NotFound ? NotFound : index + 1;
    }

    // internal method: assuming month is a three character, non-empty string
    private static string NormalizeCasing(string month)
    {
#if NET
        return string.Create(month.Length, month, (chars, name) =>
        {
            name.CopyTo(chars);
            EnsureCasing(chars);
        });
#else
        char[] chars = month.ToCharArray();
        EnsureCasing(chars);
        return new string(chars);
#endif
    }

    private static void EnsureCasing(Span<char> chars)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                chars[i] = char.ToUpperInvariant(chars[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                chars[i] = char.ToLowerInvariant(chars[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}



Expected output:
Jan: 1
Feb: 2
Mar: 3
Apr: 4
May: 5
Jun: 6
Jul: 7
Aug: 8
Sep: 9
Oct: 10
Nov: 11
Dec: 12
Empty string returns NotFound: True
Too short returns NotFound: True
Too long returns NotFound: True
Only whitespace returns NotFound: True


Please note: Here I am using he InvariantInfo which return 12 months and an empty string. There also is CurrentInfo which uses the current calendar and might return 13 actual values as there are 13 months for certain calendars. So depending on whether you need to support that you will have to choose the appropriate Info.

